# Claims aware security. Do I get it right?

Tags: authentication, authorization, wso2, claims-based-identity, adfs

I'm trying to investigate possibility of using claims aware security in the system I'm developing. The more I read about all this stuff the more confused i get. 
So i decided to describe what I know already and I would ask that You correct my statements. I got lost with all those protocols and technologies used.

Below is a simple diagram of my system. There are two services - a REST service implemented using WCF and an ASP MVC web application.
I know I need to get an STS which will be a trusted identity issuer for both of my services. I'll be using roles to differentiate certain levels of access.

[image]

The STS functionality might be accomplished by using ADFS (or is there anything more needed in addition to it) or WSO2 Identity Server.
By saying STS I mean a service which will get credentials from a client wanting to authenticate and will return a set of claims (which will beside other information contain the role assigned to the user). This set of claims will be in the form of a token.

On the diagram I marked different client types with different colors. No I'll try to describe what protocols/formats i think will be used. I am pretty confused on what is a format and what is a protocol. But let me try:

### Red scenario: rich WCF client authenticates agains REST service

1. Request to STS will be sent using WS-trust (is there any other possibility in ADFS or WSO2?). The credentials might be in one of several forms such as X.509 certificate,  password digest, kerberos, windows authentication, SAML token (this is used in federation scenarios, right?), and few other.
2. The answer to the client will be in a form of SWT token sent over OAuth protocol since this is the way we do it when trying to authenticate against REST services.

   - Does ADFS support SWT and OAuth? I couldn't find the information.
3. The client then send the token received from STS to the REST service. Once again this is SWT token on OAuth.

I guess as for the client code all can be easily implemented using Windows Identity Framework.

### Green scenario: rich android client authenticates against REST service

All protocols/formats are the same as in previous scenario. Is there any framework which can let me easily implement this?

### Blue scenario: user of web browser authenticates against ASP MVC web application

1. User goes to the web app's main page. The webapp detects that he isn't authenticated yet so redirects him to the sign on page on STS (the sign on page is on STS, right?).
2. and 3. STS authenticates the user and sends HTTP response containing SAML token and redirection to webapp. So here is HTTP used, not WS-Trusts.

Another question. In this web browser scenario there will be a cookie written on a client's machine. So whenever client will try to authenticate once again, he'll just send the cookie to sts to obtain the token. There will be no need to send the credentials. STS will issue a token basing on the cookie without any real authentication logic involved. Is that statement correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADFS / WIF out the box only supports SAML tokens - no OAuth support.

ADFS / WCF uses WS-Trust.

The sign-on page is part of ADFS.

The answer is "Yes" to your last question but (at some point) it will expire and the user will have to authenticate again.

**Update:**

Have a look at [Claims Based Identity & Access Control Guide](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any recommended way i should authenticate against REST services using ADFS then?

Comment: I've already read most relevant chapters of this book before asking. However, in the REST scenario they use their own simple issuer. There is a paragraph about using ADFS for that but there are no useful information - seems like copy paste from previous chapter. However, You helped me by answering my questions so I mark Your reply as correct answer.

Comment: There's a lot of REST related stuff on Dominick's blog - http://leastprivilege.com/?s=rest